# HDF5 file getting lost on the way when saving to disk

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, hdf5

It's all pretty straightforward: it's a script that will

1. ask the user for a time interval
2. fetch trading history for that time interval
3. store data in a pandas data frame
4. save data to 1) a .json file and 2) a .h5 file

Now, the odd thing is that the .json file will save the file to the right location ("Users/*username*/Desktop/klinehistories/"), while the .h5 file will end up in C:/users/*username*/, despite using the exact same path string for both the .json file and the .h5 file.

It can obviously not be a question of permissions, since the .json file saves to the correct location. Any clues to what this is all about? Here is the code used:

```
#create a .json file to hold the list stored in the var 

DataListBig
jsonFile = open('Users/<username>/Desktop/klinehistories/' + filename + '.json', 'w')
#create a list in .json format
dict = {'code': '200000', 'data': []}
#Store the data from DataListBig in that list
dict['data'] = DataListBig
#Store the .json object containing DataListBig in the .json file created earlier and close file
jsonFile.write(str(json.dumps(dict)))
jsonFile.close

#convert DataListBig to a data frame och store it in var df
df = pd.DataFrame(DataListBig)
#Create var h5file to store the name of the h5 file
h5file = str(filename + '.h5')
#create the .h5 file
df.to_hdf(h5file, "Users/<username>/Desktop/klinehistories/")

#open the .h5 file and print it to the screen
df1 = pd.read_hdf(h5file, "Users/<username>/Desktop/klinehistories/")
print("DataFrame read from the HDF5 file through pandas:")
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 10000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 50)
pd.set_option('display.width', 2000)
print(df1)
```

Comment: specify the *full path* for both files. That way it will be unambiguous.

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that. The script will then produce the files, but the .h5 file will still be misplaced. In addition, the following warning will show up: >>>NaturalNameWarning: object name is not a valid Python identifier: 'C:'; it does not match the pattern ``^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$``; you will not be able to use natural naming to access this object; using ``getattr()`` will still work, though
  check_attribute_name(name)